# Creating a new dataframe in R from columns of many dataframes

Tags: r

I have 150 dataframes and I want to  extract columns named 'egn' from each dataframe to make a new dataframe with 50 columns (column 'egn' from each dataframe).  The number of columns varies between 20 to 25 and the number of rows varies between 11000 to 13000.

Each of the dataframes are named: a1, a2, a3, ... , a50. 
The columns in each dataframe have the same names and I am looking to extract all the columns named egn.

This is the R code I wrote:

```
  newdataframe = 0
  for(i in 1:45) {
  txt = paste0("a.", i, "$egn")
  newdataframe= cbind(egn, eval(parse(text = txt)))
}
```

I have tried this code on different columns in the code and each column yields a differnt result ranging from a data frame only containing 3 columns, a dataframe with 46 columns and a dataframe with 1 column.
Any help would be appreciated.

Note, I think the issue is arising with my using cbind.  I have been investigating the functions aggregate() and merge().

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the datasets in a `list` (`mget(paste0("a", 1:50))`) and extract the column "egn" from each of these datasets, convert it to a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(lapply(mget(paste0("a", 1:50)), `[`, "egn"))
```

---

If the number of rows in each dataset are not the same, then use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
do.call(cbind.fill, c(lapply(mget(paste0("a", 1:50)), `[`, "egn"), fill = NA))
```

#### data

```
for(i in seq_len(50)) assign(paste0("a", i),
  value = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50*5), ncol = 50, 
      dimnames = list(NULL, sample(c(paste0("V", 1:49), "egn"))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I cannot extract column 17

Comment: @Alexander The solution is based on your description that you have data.frame and have 50 columns in each dataset.  It works on the exampel I created

Comment: Sorry.  I made an error in my description and I updated the description.  The column 'egn' is not always in col 17.

Comment: @Alexander  Then you can use the column name instead of position.  Updated the post

Comment: I am getting an error when I run that code.  Why did is rnorm(50*5)?  There are 50 columns and what does 5 represent?

Comment: @Alexander  I am just creating datasets as reproducible example to show that the code works